# What is the collective noun for arrows in motion?

Tags: collective-nouns

I've tried to look for a collective noun for arrows that are in motion and [most internet results](https://facts.co/collectivenouns/arrows/) suggest a quiver of arrows and a sheaf of arrows. However, a quiver is a container that holds arrows and a sheaf is a bundle of arrows tied together. In both these cases, the arrows are stationary.

The closest collective nouns I can think of are `rain` of arrows or `bunch` of arrows. These don't sound specific to arrows though.

Does anyone know the specific collective noun for arrows in motion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ***volley*** of arrows.

As defined in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/volley):

> 1. 
> a.  the simultaneous discharge of a number of firearms or other weapons
> b.  the bullets, arrows, etc. discharged in this way

Answer (score 4):

You may also use a **flight** of arrows. There are many examples to be found in google ngram. Here is only one of them:

> [History of |Conquest of New Spain](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_History_of_the_Conquest_of_New_Spain/4zro07zbvAsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22flight+of+arrows%22&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover)
>
> *On hearing the Cacique's shouts, the warriors attacked us in great haste and fury, and began to shoot with such skill that the first flight of arrows wounded fifteen soldiers.*

Comment: Apologies for posting the same answer. It wasn't there when I started composing mine. Took a while to check references and photograph my copy of the OED as the print is too small for me to read.

Comment: @David Thanks, but priority doesn't matter does it? It is interesting that the discussion seems to be tending towards **flight** rather than **volley**, which may have been too precipitately accepted.

Answer (score 4):

A ***flight*** of arrows.

I cannot find a dictionary example of this in an online search, perhaps because there is a [book of the same name](https://blackwells.co.uk/bookshop/product/A-Flight-of-Arrows-by-A-J-MacKenzie/9781800322790). I therefore quote from a print copy of the OED:

> 8
>  c. A volley of missiles, *esp.* arrows.

Although examples in modern English are quoted, the first, in Scots, seems rather fine to me because of the alliteration:

> Fra bowmen bald and wicht, Of fedderit flanis flew ane felloun
> **flicht** Amang the Danis.
> **1538** [Stewart *Cron. Scot.* II 605](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZaDYvAJdrRoC&pg=PA605&lpg=PA605&dq=Of+fedderit+flanis&source=bl&ots=T92Y16zHuv&sig=ACfU3U0SSmw1Ik2tDnfMhYC5u-9xHkjJ3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN75nk1ZD2AhUzQkEAHQOvB7YQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=Of%20fedderit%20flanis&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

**Flight**:

OED

> 8
>
> **c. A volley of missiles, esp. arrows.**
> 1535   W. Stewart tr. H. Boethius Bk. Cron. Scotl. (1858) II. 605   *Fra bowmen bald and wicht, Of fedderit flanis flew ane felloun **flicht** Amang the Danis.*
>
> 1869   C. Boutell tr. J. P. Lacombe Arms & Armour viii. 131   *The English archers..poured upon them their deadly arrows in flights thick as hail.*